# Creating multiple output files, with content that depends on a variable

Tags: conditionals

I'd like to write a template for a letter, which is meant to be sent to many people. Thus, the content should change slightly depending on who is the addressee. For instance, I imagine that the template could be something like the following:

```
\begin{letter}

if the addressee is A:
  \opening{Dear A,}
if the addressee is B:
  \opening{My dear B,}

...

if the addressee is B:
  By the way, I really miss you, B!

...

\end{letter}
```

Then, I'd like to create one or many pdf files with the letters, specifying somehow the list of the addressees (also a Makefile or something else would be fine for the rendering, if you can explain how to pass the name of the addressee to pdflatex).

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the `envlab` package? [`texdoc elguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/elguide)

Comment: The question is about how to create a template and render it, not about how to write a letter with LaTeX...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need, here are my ideas to tackle this.

**Solution Makefile -> Latex**

If you want the Makefile to tell Latex which "address" to use, you can use the "--jobname" flag of `pdflatex` to tell latex which job is being compiled and have if statements in latex based on the `\jobname` variable. Your Makefile will have a list of rules (one rule per jobname).
Here's an example:

```
# Assuming the main tex file is called `Main.tex`
MAIN=Main
# pdflatex flags
PDFLATEX_FLAGS= -synctex=1 --file-line-error-style --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode 
# Platform specific
PDFLATEX=pdflatex
CP=cp
RM=rm
# Define list of jobs and makefile rules
JOBNAMES:= Job1 Job2 Job3
PDFRULES:= $(foreach job, $(JOBNAMES), $(job)_pdf)

# Rule to create a pdf file
%_pdf: 
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFLATEX_FLAGS) --jobname $* $(MAIN) || echo "Failed"

all: $(PDFRULES)
```

**Solution Latex -> Makefile**

(This was what I needed). My solution consisted in having latex write a suffix to a file, and then have the makefile picking up this suffix (using `shell` and `cat`) and copying the output pdf to a new pdf file name based on this suffix. My workflow goes from Latex to the Makefile.

In latex, you can write to a file as follows:

```latex
\newwrite\myoutput
\immediate\openout\myoutput=\jobname.suffix
\write\myoutput{myAddressSuffix}
```

Where "myAddressSuffix" would be what you want to use for your output pdf file. In this example, the file `\jobname.suffix` is created. You could specify a different name based on your latex variables.

On the Makefile side, you can do something like that:

```
SUFFIXFILE:=$(MAIN).suffix

# Rule to create the .suffix
$(SUFFIXFILE):
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFLATEX_FLAGS) $(MAIN) || echo "Failed"

# Rule to create a pdf file with a different filename based on what latex wrote in the suffix file
all: $(SUFFIXFILE)
    $(CP) $(MAIN).pdf Extract-$(shell cat $(SUFFIXFILE)).pdf
    $(RM) $(SUFFIXFILE)
```

Note that it's important to have the `$(shell cat $(SUFFIXFILE))` in a separate rule than the one that creates the suffix file, and it's important to delete the suffix file if you want to trigger a new compilation.

Comment: "use the "--jobname" flag of pdflatex to tell latex which job is being compiled and have if statements in latex based on the \jobname variable"  I feel like this is the piece that OP needs, and the piece that you leave out.

Answer (score 1):

This produces all the letters in a single PDF. I then either print the PDF or split it using an external tool (`pdftk`, but there are other options).

You prepare two files: a data file and a template. `textmerg` is used to merge the data into the template. I have done this for letters for a while, but I regularly use this to produce student feedback and assessment paperwork.

The example below demonstrates how to change the recipient's name and address, but you can define as many data fields as you wish for as many points in the template as you want. This can be used to fit marks and comments into categories for students, for example, or to customise a sentence such as `Please find enclosed \enclosures.` in a letter. Lines in the data file may be left blank where applicable and it is also possible (and sometimes convenient) to generate the data file from another data source, such as a csv file or spreadsheet.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{\jobname.dat}
Sandy Manner
32 Dither Close
Fowllands
Megalopolis
Archaemeleon
XR76 2BW
Alex the Great
768 Lessened Street
End of the Line
Catacombatron
Badlands
BL43 2EL
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\begin{document}
\Fields{\addressee\street\district\city\county\postcode}
\name{Your Name}
\address{53 Your Street\\Your Area\\Your Town\\Your County\\YR12 3PC}
\Merge{\jobname.dat}{%
  \begin{letter}{\addressee\\\street\\\district\\\city\\\county\\\postcode}
    \opening{Dear \addressee,}
    This is to inform you that I am sending you this letter.
    \closing{Yours fatalistically,}
  \end{letter}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: results of merging data for two letters]